# JYTHON Calculating the number of pixels in a picture

Tags: python, image, jython, pixel

Working on a program that can calculate the number of black,white or red pixels in a room. (ill use black for the example)

I've tried to get this to work but I cant for the life of me.

## Assume that all of my mediapaths have already been set.

```
i = 0
for p in get pixels(picture):
   if p == black
      count = count + 1
return count
```

Any ideas? Im only just beginning with Jython so apologies if its blatantly obvious. Thank you.

Comment: What goes wrong? Can you cut & paste your actual code? The sample provided has errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a a few issues with your code.  Try this and see if it works.  You can adjust the RGB values to count red and white pixels as well.

```
count = 0
for p in getPixels(picture):
    r = getRed(p)
    b = getBlue(p)
    g = getGreen(p)
    if (r,g,b) == (0,0,0):
        count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I see what I'm doing wrong, thank you very much Andrew.
Would it be fair to say that If I was looking for the red pixels in an image along with the black I'd do something like:
count = 0
count1=0
for p in getPixels(picture):
    r = getRed(p)
    b = getBlue(p)
    g = getGreen(p)
    if (r,g,b) == (0,0,0):
        count = count + 1
    if (r,g,b) == (0,255,0):
        count1 = count1 + 1
    return count
    return count1